# How to move on drag&drop between ListGrids in SmartGwt

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I'm writing SmartGWT application, and I have two list grids and some records inside.
I have setDragDataAction to MOVE. But there occurres problem, when I drag&drop records, they always copy instead of move, but if I use transferSelectedData method it's OK. When I drag&drop into same ListGrid there is the same problem, records are copied, not moved.

Is there way to set drag&drop action to move, not copy?

Answer (score 0):

The method setDragDataAction(DragDataAction.MOVE) shall do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some tests, here is the conclusion : **whenever there is a databound list of records, the setDragDataAction(DragDataAction.MOVE) is not working**. If it's not databound, it works. Any suggestions for a workaround?